# JSDOM and jQuery not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, jsdom, react-dom

I'm pretty new to the test environment such as mocha and chai and I want to practice by following online tutorial but it seems that it does not like what I do and gives me an error saying:

```
global.document = _jsdom2.default.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
                                  ^
TypeError: _jsdom2.default.jsdom is not a function
```

My `test_helper` looks like,

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import TestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../src/reducers';
import chaiJquery from 'chai-jquery';

// Set up testing environment to run like a browser in the command line
global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;

const $ = jquery(global.window);

// Build 'renderComponent' helper that should render a given react class
function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props, state) {
  const componentInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers,state)}>
      <ComponentClass {...props}/>
    </Provider>
  );

  return $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance)); // produces HTML
}
// Build helper for simulating(or other) event

// Set up chai-jquery
chaiJquery(chai, chai.util, $);

export default { renderComponent, expect };
```

I was wondering that anyone has similar kind of issue like mine and know how to figure this out. Since I am not really familiar with this subject, I'm not sure how I can debug this.

---

Here is the error stack after I implemented `const { JSDOM } = jsdom;` and `new JSDOM(...)`

```
    if ( !w.document ) {
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/cheewoonkim/Desktop/nodeapp/meanmapsapp/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:30:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cheewoonkim/Desktop/nodeapp/meanmapsapp/test/test_helper.js:17:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at loader (/Users/cheewoonkim/Desktop/nodeapp/meanmapsapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/cheewoonkim/Desktop/nodeapp/meanmapsapp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/cheewoonkim/Desktop/nodeapp/meanmapsapp/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:355:3
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cheewoonkim/Desktop/nodeapp/meanmapsapp/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:354:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:538:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! budee_order_tracking@1.0.0 test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the budee_order_tracking@1.0.0 test script 'mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test "--watch"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the budee_order_tracking package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test "--watch"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs budee_order_tracking
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls budee_order_tracking
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cheewoonkim/.npm/_logs/2017-05-16T01_20_20_200Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! budee_order_tracking@1.0.0 test:watch: `npm run test -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the budee_order_tracking@1.0.0 test:watch script 'npm run test -- --watch'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the budee_order_tracking package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run test -- --watch
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs budee_order_tracking
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls budee_order_tracking
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cheewoonkim/.npm/_logs/2017-05-16T01_20_20_215Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Should be `jsdom.JSDOM(...)`

Comment: @AndrewLi jsdome.JSDOM(...) does not work :(

Comment: You have an extra e there

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry that was my typo but it still doesn't work

Comment: Has the error changed at all?

Comment: Actually yes, `global.document = _jsdom2.default.JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
                                  ^

TypeError: Class constructor JSDOM cannot be invoked without 'new'` like this.

Comment: but it still does not work without a new keyword

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it should be `jsdom.JSDOM`. Per the [documentation](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/README.md):

> #### Basic usage
>
> ```
> const jsdom = require("jsdom");
> const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
> ```
>
> To use `jsdom`, you will primarily use the `JSDOM` **constructor**, which is a **named export of the `jsdom` main module**.

Second of all, `JSDOM` *is a constructor* as noted above, so you must use the `new` keyword:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';

global.document = new jsdom.JSDOM(...);
```

I would use named importing to import a specific named export to make this easier:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

global.document = new JSDOM(...);
```

Finally, use `window` instead of `defaultView` which *doesn't exist* in the new API. It returns `undefined` and that's why jQuery won't work:

```
const $ = jquery(global.document.window);
```

Answer (score 0):

A different syntax:

```
import jsdom from "jsdom";
import chai from "chai";
//...

global.doc = new jsdom.JSDOM("...");
global.window = doc.window;
```

The `new` operator is important here since JSDOM cannot be invoked without it.